# Making html page appear on click of submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make another page to appear when I click certain button, I basically know how to do this, but this time I am in trouble.I have following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

   <!--See siin all tekstiväli--> 
     <H3>Minu küsitlused </H3>

<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<ol>

<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimustik_pealkiri');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $titles[] = $row['pealkiri'];

 }

foreach($titles as $title) {

 ?>

<li>
    <?php echo $title ?>

    <form action='Minu_kysitlused_1.php'>
      <input type="button" name = "saada" value="saada">
      <input type="button" value="tulemused">
      <input type="button" value="lõpeta ennetähtaegselt">
      <input type="button" value="X">
    </li>
   </form>

<?php
}
?>
</ol>


</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['saada'])){
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/saada.html'>";
}

?>
```

Everything works just fine but when I click button 'saada' nothing happens. What should I do to make saada.html appear on this click?

Comment: what is your page url you need to add this in action or in header function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
<form action='Minu_kysitlused_1.php'  method="post">
```

Missing:

```
 method="post"
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this
header function must be First thing to sent as html otherwise it will not work

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['saada'])){
    header( "Location : localhost/Praks/saada.html");
    die();
     }

    ?>


<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

   <!--See siin all tekstiväli--> 
     <H3>Minu küsitlused </H3>

<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<ol>

<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimustik_pealkiri');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $titles[] = $row['pealkiri'];

 }

foreach($titles as $title) {

 ?>

<li>
    <?php echo $title ?>

    <form action='Minu_kysitlused_1.php'>
      <input type="button" name = "saada" value="saada">
      <input type="button" value="tulemused">
      <input type="button" value="lõpeta ennetähtaegselt">
      <input type="button" value="X">
    </li>
   </form>

<?php
}
?>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

second approach

```
<form action="your-url">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="saada"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: It reloads now, when i click 'saada' but wanted page still doesn't appear. Only saada=saada appears on the end of url.

Comment: i understand where is your saada.html file exists ?

Comment: ok open your browser and load ur both pages copy your both pages url and paste in end of  your Question let me see your urls :)

Comment: place localhost/Praks/saada.html first in your action= "(here)"

Answer (score 0):

why you try with meta tag 
You just put header("location:yourpagename");

just like below

```
if(isset($_POST['saada'])){
 header("Location:http://localhost/Praks/saada.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in first time, I don't understand why do you use the form tag to call a page, if there aren't any data passed via POST?

Anyway, in your foreach cicle you can use a very simple collection of link:

```
foreach($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
    echo '<a href="page1.php">Link 1</a>';
    echo '<a href="page2.php">Link 2</a>';
    echo '<a href="page3.php">Link 3</a>';
    echo '<a href="page4.php">Link 4</a>';
}
```

This solution is too clean.
Bye
Marco